# @mouseup not firing if a $set is called

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component with a table row and I want to mark a continuous selection of the cells with the mouse.
the goal I'm aiming at is: mousedown on one cell to start marking cells, while still holding the mouse button move the mouse to mark every cell where the mouse is hovering over; releasing the mouse button stops marking the cells.

the table looks like this (based on an arry of td-objects):

```
<table @mouseleave="stopSelect()" @mouseup="stopSelect()">
    <tr>
        <td v-for="td in tds" v-bind:class="{ 'selected': td.active }"
            @mousedown="startSelect($index)" 
            @mouseover="setover($index)"
            >.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and these are my methods:

```
setover (i) {
    if(this.mouseIsDown) {
        this.tds.$set(i, {active: true});
    }
},
stopSelect () {
    this.mouseIsDown = false;
},
startSelect (i) {
    this.tds.forEach(function (it) {
            it.active = false;
    });
    this.mouseIsDown = true;
    this.setover(i);
},
```

this works mostly fine (mousedown and mouseover that is), only the mouseup-event does not get recognized, as long as setover() has the $set-call in it. 
then the only way to stop the 'selection-mode' is to leave the row with the mouse, triggering the @mouseleave of the table.
when i remove the $set-call in the setover method, the mouseup events are recognized as intended.

so my question is: why has the $set-call an influence on the mouseup-event and how do i get around this?

Comment: Probably because your chanhe to the data makes the component re-render, and in the process, the element that the event was registered on, gets replaced with a new one or something. Use a key attribute to prevent that. If it still happens, provide a live example on jafiddle or codepen, please.

Comment: Addendum: since it seems you use Vue 1.0, instead of key, it's `track-by`

Comment: Also try mouseenter instead of mouseover

Comment: just adding track-by did the trick, thank you so much for your advice!